# Google maps API showing empty page in my ionic app

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic4

I am trying to implement google maps API in my ionic app. All seemed to go fine but strangely I can't see anything on my page.
This is the process I followed. (Seems straightforward)

added script to my index.html head
`<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**********q3aC1a*****POEp5O**********&libraries=places"></script>`

declared google variable:
`declare var google;`

added view child for the element in my HTML
`@ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapNativeElement: ElementRef;`

`<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map">
  </div>
</ion-content>`

then added the call in afterContentInit:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
      this.mapNativeElement.nativeElement,
      {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
      }
    )
  }
```

this is my full .ts file

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  map;
  @ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapNativeElement: ElementRef;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
      this.mapNativeElement.nativeElement,
      {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you set height and width of div?

Comment: @Chellappan I feel so dumb. This resolved my issue. Thank you so much,